# sql diplay sum result

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

how can i display the sum result of query into the following grid view :

```
string raf5 = string.Format("select SUM(orderDetails.unitPrice) from orderDetails INNER JOIN Orderz ON orderDetails.orderId=Orderz.Id AND Orderz.customerId={0} ", k);
SqlCommand comm5 = new SqlCommand(raf5, c);
SqlDataReader r55 = comm17.ExecuteReader();
DataTable ts = new DataTable();
ts.Columns.Add("Total Sum", typeof(string));
while (r55.Read())
{
    ts.Rows.Add(r55["unitPrice"].ToString());
}
c.Close();
GridView3.DataSource = ts;
GridView3.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am guessing it throws exception on  line `ts.Rows.Add(r55["unitPrice"].ToString());`

Comment: Why are you using `GridView` to display `sum`?

Comment: @J.Steen because of `ts.Rows.Add`?

Comment: There's also the mystifying comm5 and comm17 - is that entirely correct?

Comment: First try to add breakpoint in your code to see what is wrong with the code or logic. It is the best way to find the problems in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is a missing column name.
You need to specify a column name for your sum like this:

```
string raf5 = string.Format("select SUM(orderDetails.unitPrice) as unitPrice from orderDetails INNER JOIN Orderz ON orderDetails.orderId=Orderz.Id AND Orderz.customerId={0} ", k);
```

Or, you could get the column by index in data reader:

```
ts.Rows.Add(r55[0].ToString());
```

Also, you're returning a single value so you're better off with `(decimal)com17.ExecuteScalar()`.

Comment: I reedited my code as you told me but the grid view shown the prices not the total price which is the sum .

Comment: @ToOt, try debugging the method. First of all execute the query in sql editor. If the query returns desired output, try seeing what's in the table which is bound to the gridview.